# How to select Views as a Context reaction block?

Tags: views, 7

I would like to create a new Context (Drupal 7.39) and choose Blocks as reaction. In blocks, I would like to choose a specific View and add it to a region. However, 'Views' is not in the list on the right (where it says nodes, search, system, users, etc). In other sites I manage, Views is part of that reaction>blocks list.

Does anyone have any idea why it might not be listed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve you requirement please follow the steps below.

1. In view configuration, under advance settings select **Exposed form in block** as a *Yes*.
   [image]
2. Now you can see your **view** listed at right side.

> Please remember, only blocks can be place into region, thats why you
>   have to first expose your view as block.

Comment: You are most welcome :)